# C# app and asp.NET session

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, wsdl

I try build client-base desktop app using webservices. I have problem when I try send List through session. Even though the session was created, when reference back to session no longer exists.

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public void dodajdolisty(string login) {
    bool jest = false;

    if (Session["uzytkownicy"] != null) {
        listaOsob = (List<string>)Session["uzytkownicy"];

        foreach (string s in listaOsob) {
            if (s == login) { jest = true; break; }
        }

        if (! jest) {
            listaOsob.Add(login);
            Session["uzytkownicy"] = listaOsob;
        }
    }
    else {
        listaOsob.Add(login);
        // the debugger shows that the session has been created
        Session["uzytkownicy"] = listaOsob;
    }
}

public List<string> pobierzzlisty() {
    List<string> list = new List<string>();
    list = (List<string>)Session["uzytkownicy"]; // session is null

    return list;
} // null
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Where are the methods `dodajdolisty()` and `pobierzzlisty()` being called? PS: **Love** those names

Comment: for example here (C# app using WSDL) ' web.dodajdolisty("ddddd");
            foreach (string s in web.pobierzzlisty())///error {
                listView1.Items.Add(s); //web is Class generated by WSDL.exe
 }'

Comment: It is not recommended to put non serializable objects into the session collection. It only works for in-memory session state but not for e.g. the SQL Server session state provider since it cannot be serialized then. This is just a warning so if you for any reason plan to change the session state provider later.

Comment: @Chris so what should I do using array? But I do not know how many objects will be stored

Comment: @Aristos first i set session next i get this session

Comment: @Chris List<string> is indeed serializable since String is serializable

Comment: @Aristos first metod 'dodajdolisty()' create session next 'pobierzzlisty()' metod get session. when I run it in browser these metod work correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you missed to add cookiecontainer on client app, try this

```
MyWebService ws= new MyWebService();
ws.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();
```